# What does it mean when $MaxLicenseProcesses returns Infinity?

Tags: parallelization, kernel, remote-access, kernel-startup

I am learning how to use Mathematica on a cluster, and a lot of this stuff is still way over my head. Please let me know if I am missing any crucial details.

The cluster uses Linux and uses Lmod to manage software modules. When I log into my account I then load Mathematica using the command `ml Mathematica/12.0.0`, and then I start a Mathematica kernel using `math`. Once the kernel is up, I put in the command `$MaxLicenseProcesses` or `$MaxLicenseSubprocesses` and I get back "Infinity".

What does "Infinity" mean here? If I run this on a notebook on my own computer it tells me 8 for `$MaxLicenseProcesses` and 16 `$MaxLicenseSubprocesses`. I am assuming this corresponds to the largest number I can use in `LaunchKernels[n]`, since on my own computer if I try `LaunchKernels[17]` I get an error.

Does this mean I can use any number with the `LaunchKernels[]` function? At what point does this become pointless in speeding things up? When I try parallel computations on my own computer, specifying `LaunchKernels[16]` vs the automatic `LaunchKernels[]` which launches 2 kernels doesn't seem to create much improvement (as opposed to getting 16 kernels on the cluster which speeds up my calculations by a factor of 12).

Comment: It's not `$MaxLicenseProcessors`. It is `$MaxLicenseProcesses`. I corrected it in the title. It means that you have a license that does not put a limit on the number of Mathematica instances you can run at the same time.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ugh thanks. I honestly do that so many times when typing it out haha.